# How to select this rows based on two columns and a min function

Tags: sql, db2

I greatly appreciate all help for writing a select query for this.

**MyTable**

```
 sw_id | url_id |  open_date   | valid
----------------------------------------
  101  |  com   |  2013-01-01  |  1
  202  |  net   |  2013-01-02  |  1
  202  |  net   |  2013-02-02  |  1 
  303  |  com   |  2013-01-03  |  1 
  303  |  com   |  2013-02-03  |  1 
  303  |  com   |  2013-03-03  |  1 
  404  |  org   |  2013-01-04  |  1 
  404  |  org   |  2013-02-04  |  1 
  404  |  gov   |  2013-02-04  |  1
  404  |  gov   |  2013-04-04  |  1 
  ...
```

> We need to find the valid (valid=1) rows where same sw_id, url_id got less open_date.
>
> **select query should output the rows from above something like this:**

**Query output**

```
 sw_id | url_id |  open_date   | valid  |  min_open_d 
-----------------------------------------------------
  202  |  net   |  2013-02-02  |  1     |  2013-01-02
  303  |  com   |  2013-02-03  |  1     |  2013-01-03
  303  |  com   |  2013-03-03  |  1     |  2013-01-03
  404  |  org   |  2013-02-04  |  1     |  2013-01-04
  404  |  gov   |  2013-04-04  |  1     |  2013-02-04
```

As you can see, we select only the rows that have open_date higher than the lowest, min(open_date).

I hope you understand the problem from the description above.

Comment: Can you please paste what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I have two different queries which I'm not satisfied with. I would appreciate receive new ideas rather than showing those queries. But if you really want to look at them, see here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485480/update-query-combined-by-group-and-set-minimum-dates)

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you showed your own effort here as well, but basically subqueries is one of the (easiest for newbie to understand) ways to do it.

```
SELECT
    sw_id,
    url_id,
    open_date,
    valid,
    (
        SELECT MIN(open_date)
        FROM MyTable t2
        WHERE t2.sw_id = t1.sw_id GROUP BY t2.sw_id
    ) AS min_open_d
FROM
    MyTable t1
WHERE
    valid = 1
ORDER BY
    open_date DESC
```

Comment: The group by should be based on both sw_id and url_id, I think this will also show the 101 sw_id, I would like to have those (sw and url id) who does not have any "less open date" excluded from the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample and explanation leaves a little bit open to interpretation but something like this should be close.

```
SELECT  sw_id ,
        url_id ,
        open_date ,
        valid ,
        ( SELECT    MIN(open_date)
          FROM      mytable mt2
          WHERE     mt2.sw_id = mt1.sw_id
                    AND mt1.url_id = mt2.url_id
          GROUP BY mt2.sw_id, mt2.url_id
        ) AS min_open_d
FROM    mytable mt1
WHERE   valid = 1 AND mt1.open_date >          
        ( SELECT    MIN(open_date)
          FROM      mytable mt3
          WHERE     mt3.sw_id = mt1.sw_id
                    AND mt1.url_id = mt3.url_id
          GROUP BY mt3.sw_id, mt3.url_id
        )
```

Comment: I will try this soon, I would like to exclude rows who does not have any "less open date". E.g. sw_id 101 and the first occurrence of 202. Thank you @RThomas

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved a bit more elegantly with OLAP functions:

```
select * from (
    select sw_id, 
           url_id, 
           open_date, 
           valid, 
           min(open_date) over (partition by sw_id,url_id) as min_open_d
       from MyTable
       where valid = 1
    )
    where open_date <> min_open_d;
```

This should also be more efficient than a subquery.